# Testing NestJS Validation Pipe not working

Tags: jestjs, automated-tests, nestjs

I have a simple class I am trying to get to work with NestJS and End To End testing to ensure I can get the validations working properly, but I cannot get the validations to work.  If I send the data with Postman, or a normal client, the application does respond with the proper error.

API.dto.ts

```
import { IsNumber, IsPositive, IsString } from 'class-validator';
export class ApiDTO {
    @IsString() public readonly FileName:string;
    @IsNumber() @IsPositive() public readonly StatusCode:number;
    @IsNumber() @IsPositive() public readonly TimeOut:number;
}
```

E2E Test File

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import * as request from 'supertest';

import { INestApplication, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

import { AppModule } from '@APP/app.module';
import { ApiDTO } from './../../src/api/api.dto';

describe('ApiController (e2e)', () => {
    let app: INestApplication;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
            imports: [AppModule],
        }).compile();

        app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
        app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
        await app.init();
    });

    it('/api/test/ (POST) test to see data validation works', async done => {
        const RequestBody:ApiDTO = {
            FileName : 'README.md',
            StatusCode: 111,
            TimeOut: -25
        };
        const Expected:string = `${RequestBody.FileName} = ${RequestBody.StatusCode.toString()} after ${RequestBody.TimeOut.toString()}`;

        const ResponseData = await request(app.getHttpServer())
            .post('/api/test')
            .send(RequestBody)
            .set('Accept', 'application/json');

        // All of these will fail as the code returns a 200 OK, as it does not do the validation (TimeOut -25 should fail IsPositive())
        expect(ResponseData.status).toBe(400);
        expect(ResponseData.headers['content-type']).toContain('application/json');

        // This line caused the problem as body is an object
        //expect(ResponseData.body.length).toBeGreaterThan(2);

        expect(ResponseData.body.statusCode).toBe(400);
        expect(ResponseData.body.message[0]).toBe('TimeOut must be a positive number');
        expect(ResponseData.body.error).toBe('Bad Request');
        done();         
    });

});
```

I get a successful return, 200, when making this call.  My code should be failing, due to the TimeOut with a negative number, where it needs to be `IsPositive()`. The service and other code all runs, just not the validations. I have added the global pipes in the beforeEach() so not sure what else to check.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the mistake in my tests.  Once I added the ValidationPipe() into the app definition:

```
app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());   // <- This addition
await app.init();
```

This then enabled the validation to run properly.  The tests were failing, as I was checking the length of the response body,

```
it('/api/test/ (POST) test to see data validation works', async done => {
    ...
    expect(ResponseData.body.length).toBeGreaterThan(10);
    ...
    done();         
});
```

The ResponseData.body is an object, so the `.length` of the object is invalid.  Removing this expectation solved my issue.

```
it('/api/test/ (POST) test to see data validation works', async done => {
    const RequestBody:ApiDTO = {
        FileName : 'README.md',
        StatusCode: 111,
        TimeOut: -25
    };
    const Expected:string = `${RequestBody.FileName} = ${RequestBody.StatusCode.toString()} after ${RequestBody.TimeOut.toString()}`;

    const ResponseData = await request(app.getHttpServer())
        .post('/api/test')
        .send(RequestBody)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json');

    expect(ResponseData.status).toBe(400);
    expect(ResponseData.headers['content-type']).toContain('application/json');
    
    expect(ResponseData.body.statusCode).toBe(400);
    expect(ResponseData.body.message[0]).toBe('TimeOut must be a positive number');
    expect(ResponseData.body.error).toBe('Bad Request');
    done();         
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Removing my node_modules folder and reinstalling it worked for me.

Steps:

- Remove `/node_modules`
- Re run `npm install`

Comment: Don't think it will solve the problem for other folks